# Displaying the bootstrap page in JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am trying to display the more than one `div` into JQuery code.So basically it is the bootstrap.

Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var element = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title" id="panel_title">Demo</h3></div><div class="panel-body"><div id=print_received_table></div></div></div>';
$('#result').append(element);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is not displaying anything. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

Please someone suggest me on this and help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You code works](http://codepen.io/tplummer/pen/XmpXrX), but you need some extra steps to make it work more than once.

If you're trying to put more than one instance of `element` into `#result`, you'll need to run a loop separate instances of `.append()`.

**EDIT** @Pankaj also notes wrapping your script in `$(document).ready()` which is probably a good idea as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = [1,2,3];

    $.each(obj, function(i, v){
      $('#new-result').append(element);
    });
})
```

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer you feel is most relevant to help future users who may view this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use $(document).ready()

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
 var element = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title" id="panel_title">Demo</h3></div><div class="panel-body"><div id=print_received_table></div></div></div>';
$('#result').append(element);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move your script before closing body,because on that period of time DOM is not ready and you try to append to DOM. OR You can use [document.ready event](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)/ immediate function ((function () {  // ... })();).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var element = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title" id="panel_title">Demo</h3></div><div class="panel-body"><div id=print_received_table></div></div></div>';
    $('#result').append(element);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```